# Symfony 4 - Send Mail with ionos

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

For several hours, I can not send mail with Symfony 4. Currently, I am hosted at IONOS and I wish to send emails through my email present in the host. Symfony is sending me the following error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Swift_TransportException: "Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection timed out # 110].

I want the emails to send directly so I commented on the content of the `swiftmailer.yaml`

```
#swiftmailer:
    # ...
    # spool: { type: memory }

#.env
    # APP_ENV=prod
    # MAILER_URL=smtp://imap.ionos.fr:993?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=mail&password=passwordmail


#Controller
    # $message = (new \Swift_Message('Youpi Email'))
    # ->setFrom(mail)
    # ->setTo('mail@gmail.com')
    # ->setBody($params['message'],'text/plain')
    # $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

IONOS email configuration is here :

[Mail configuration IONOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyaLF.png)

Thank you a lot for your responses !

Comment: The contents of the .env file and the controller are not commented obviously

Comment: Can you try `MAILER_URL=smtp://LOGIN:PASSWORD@imap.ionos.fr:993?timeout=60&encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login` (replace the LOGIN/PASSWORD with yours) and uncomment your `swiftmailer` yaml ?

Comment: Ugo T. Salut Ugo ! I still have the same mistake `Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection timed out #110]` and I removed the cache before doing the manipulation

Comment: I don't know, the error message sounds like you're not using the .env config, when it reports it cannot connect to "localhost". (I'm also confused, that the smtp server is supposed to be at *imap*.ionos.fr ... since imap != smtp.

Comment: Have you set the value `transport: mail` in your swiftmailer yaml conf ?

Comment: @UgoT. , transport: mail is deprecated and doesn't work in my project.

Comment: @Jakumi, I updated my post with the configuration available in IONOS

Comment: sending mail usually is done over smtp - the  very start of the mailer_url ("smtp://") should have given you the hint. try the smtp server instead smtp.ionos.fr:465

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to IONOS mailing server from your localhost, it's a restriction from ionos.

You have to try it on your hosting server.

```
protocol = 'smtp'
Host = "smtp.ionos.fr"; / Port = 587;
Host = "smtp.ionos.com"; / Port = 465;
```

Note that the PORT depends on the hosting domain.

[ionos france smtp config](https://www.ionos.fr/assistance/email/utiliser-ses-comptes-de-messagerie-sur-smartphones-android/configurer-un-compte-de-messagerie-sur-smartphone-android/)